# subsetting arules by lhs in R

Tags: r, subset, apriori

I want to subset the rules produced by running apiriori algorithm in R in the following manner.

The rule subset must have LHS which has to only have any of the items in another list(say items). No constraints are applied on RHS.

I tried the following code but I couldn't get the results as expected:

```
> library(arules)
> library(datasets)
> data(Groceries)
> rules <- apriori(Groceries, parameter = list(supp = 0.001, conf = 0.8))
inspect(head(rules))
    lhs                                 rhs            support     confidence lift     
[1] {liquor,red/blush wine}          => {bottled beer} 0.001931876 0.9047619  11.235269
[2] {curd,cereals}                   => {whole milk}   0.001016777 0.9090909   3.557863
[3] {yogurt,cereals}                 => {whole milk}   0.001728521 0.8095238   3.168192
[4] {butter,jam}                     => {whole milk}   0.001016777 0.8333333   3.261374
[5] {soups,bottled beer}             => {whole milk}   0.001118454 0.9166667   3.587512
[6] {napkins,house keeping products} => {whole milk}   0.001321810 0.8125000   3.179840

items = c("curd","cereals")
rules.subset2 <- subset(rules, subset = all(lhs %in% items))
```

This sub-setting operation results in the following (which is wrong because I only want to have "curd and cereals" as LHS in the rule-subset)

```
inspect(head(rules.subset2))
          lhs                                                                           rhs                support     confidence lift     
    [1]   {liquor,red/blush wine}                                                    => {bottled beer}     0.001931876 0.9047619  11.235269
    [2]   {curd,cereals}                                                             => {whole milk}       0.001016777 0.9090909   3.557863
    [3]   {yogurt,cereals}                                                           => {whole milk}       0.001728521 0.8095238   3.168192
    [4]   {butter,jam}                                                               => {whole milk}       0.001016777 0.8333333   3.261374
    [5]   {soups,bottled beer}                                                       => {whole milk}       0.001118454 0.9166667   3.587512
    [6]   {napkins,house keeping products}                                           => {whole milk}       0.001321810 0.8125000   3.179840
```

I tried finding answers on this web site but no luck. I also tried various other methods but I was not successful.

I would appreciate any help from you.

Comment: Did you find the answer? I think none of the answers apply

Answer (score 2):

It worked when I tried this:

`rules.subset2 <- subset(rules, lhs %in% c("cereals", "curd"))`

Multi-step to include "cereals" and "curd" in lhs at the same time:

`sub_2<- subset(rules, lhs %in% "cereals")`
`sub_3<- subset(sub_2, lhs %in% "curd")`

Comment: Thanks @jiayao. This one gives all rules that have at least one of the items at LHS. Here is the output of the statement that you suggested: `hs                             rhs                support     confidence
[1] {curd,cereals}               => {whole milk}       0.001016777 0.9090909 
[2] {yogurt,cereals}             => {whole milk}       0.001728521 0.8095238 
[3] {turkey,curd}                => {other vegetables} 0.001220132 0.8000000`. But I need the R command to get the rules that have only the items in "items" vector not any item

Comment: Oh Ok, so you want only "cereals" and "curd" in lhs at the same time.  I played a little in rstudio, but didn't figure out a way to do this in one line, but I think you can do this in multiple steps.  `sub_2<- subset(rules, lhs %in% "cereals")`  `sub_3<- subset(sub_2, lhs %in% "curd")`  I will keeping googling around.

Answer (score 2):

I think the operator is `%ain%`, so something like:

```
lhs %oin% c('cereals', 'curd')
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has an example given

```
## select only rules with items "age=Young" and "workclass=Private" in
## the left-hand-side
rules.sub <- subset(rules, subset = lhs %ain% 
    c("age=Young", "workclass=Private"))
```